# Granting permissions to analysis services SQL Server 2014 with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, sql-server-administration

I am trying to deploy my first cube in SSAS but the deployment fails because a connection isn't established.  The problem is related to giving privileges to SSAS from windows.  It seems I have to create or change privileges to something called Local Windows Security Group that is associated with the SSAS.

I found a document on the internet that describes how to do it, but I am not a security expert and was not able to follow  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175371(v=sql.120).aspx
Within the above document it says: The permission holder in Analysis Services is not the logon account, but a local Windows security group created by Setup that contains the per-service SID. Assigning permissions to the security group is consistent with previous versions of Analysis Services.

Anyone can explain how to connect to SSAS when you're on a local machine with windows authentication in simple English would be greatly appreciated.

The exact error message is: Error   13  Parser: The syntax for the ImpersonationInfo object is incorrect. If the ImpersonateAccount value is used for ImpersonationInfo, then the Account property cannot be empty.     0   0

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error you're getting. I've never needed to make any changes to local security to be able to access SSAS.

Comment: The solution in the past (past versions) used to be : Right-click on data source in solution explorer and Select "View Designer", then
go to "Impersonation info" tab and select Default option.  I tried all options on that tab and non worked.